# How to change color scheme of Keynote slide design/template?

Tags: keynote, iwork

I just made the switch to Mac. In PowerPoint, I used to be able to select a certain slide theme or design but choose a different color of it. How can I do that with Keynote? I've been googling for hours just to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by “colour scheme”?

Comment: Like for example, when I select a slide design that has exactly the same appearance or layout but of a different color.

Comment: You mean the background image and the colour of the text on the slide?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Although I don't really care much about the text color--just the slide's design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change the appearance of all the slides:

1. While creating a new document, choose any template.
2. From the menubar, select View > Show Master Slides.
3. Select the layout you want to edit from the navigator pane on the left.
4. On the Toolbar, click on Inspector (“i” icon).
5. Choose the second tab icon (slide icon) in the Inspector window. Click on Appearance.
6. Here you can specify any background for the slide. It can be an image, a colour, a gradient or a tint.

If you just want to change the appearance of the current slide, follow steps 4 to 6.

To change the style of text for all the slides:

1. Follow steps 1 to 4.
2. Choose the capital “T” icon in the Inspector window.
3. Select the text whose colour, font, etc. you want to change.
4. In the inspector window, there are various properties like text colour, character spacing, etc. which you can change.
5. You can change the font from the toolbar.

To change the style of text for the current slide, just follow the steps without opening the master slide.

Comment: I see. I suppose I can't do it in the same way I used to be able to via PowerPoint. When I replace the slide's appearance with a color fill or a gradient, the entire background changes and does not simply become a different color of the same look.

Comment: You can’t do that. You can’t change the colour of the pattern from within Keynote. You will have to find the image, change the colour, and add it back to Keynote.

Comment: I don't understand your explanation. For example, I am on the harmony theme on keynote and I want to know how to change the background color which is now a teal color to purple. How would I do that?

Comment: @CallmeBlondie You will have to change the background image for that. Look at the first set of steps. Follow them and you can change the background image for your presentation

Answer (score 2):

there's a simpler answer. choose whatever slides you want to use, go to view> lightable, then choose command A (select All), go to Format on the right and edit background as you want.